# Is it possible to override specific Bootstrap4 styles/variables at runtime?

Tags: css, sass, bootstrap-4, themes, meteor-blaze

I've inherited a project using Bootstrap4 for layout and styling but needs now to support hot swapping of certain base styles (for example font-face, primary and background colour) at runtime.

The site runs on a single theme bootstrap styles, but certain users - once logged in - need to have some root values overwritten.

All posts/advice I've found focuses on creating a custom theme at build - this approach, though possible, requires a separate build each time we add a new client variation. Ideally we want a single central theme which we can over write a few custom styles - ideally injected from a API call.

The stack is using Meteor 1.8 with Blaze as the UI framework - though I'm not aware of any native methods within those from handling this so expect it needs either:
 * a pure JS solution like a conditional require of a css file
 * dynamically creating a stylesheet such as

```
var style = document.createElement('style');
document.head.appendChild(style);
style.sheet.insertRule('#target {color: white}');
```

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand of your post, you should look at DocHead package by kadirahq (https://github.com/kadirahq/meteor-dochead).

I've used Session here to save the selected theme. There might be other ways to do it but this was working fine for me.

I've used it to allow any user to choose his own bootstrap theme.

For exemple, you can have a select containing your styles :

```
<select>
    <option id="themes/first.css">First</option>
    <option id="themes/second.css">Second</option>
    <option id="themes/third.css">Third</option>
</select>
```

Then you can select the default theme in a onRendered for example :

```
Template.myTemplate.onRendered(function() {
    if (Session.get("theme") != undefined) {
        DocHead.addLink(Session.get("theme"));
        document.getElementById("selectedTheme").value = Session.get("themeName");
    }
});
```

Add a helper :

```
getThemeName() {
    return Session.get("themeName");
}
```

And finally, an event handler on your select :

```
'change select'(event) {
    DocHead.removeDocHeadAddedTags()
    Session.setPersistent("themeName", event.target.value);
    var themeURL = event.target.selectedOptions[0].id;
    var linkInfo = {rel: "stylesheet", href: themeURL};
    Session.setPersistent("theme", linkInfo);
    DocHead.addLink(linkInfo);
},
```

I've removed this feature from my project few month ago so there might be some issues, but It should work.

Good luck :)